# can i create project in google developer console programmatically

Tags: google-api

I want to create project in `google` console programmatically and create new key in this project automatically using java code .is that possible or is any library to do this?

Comment: No I don't think this is possible. I searched and couldn't find any info about it being possible https://developers.google.com/console/help/#creatingdeletingprojects

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is nothing as yet that will allow you to programmatically create a project in Google Developer console.   I would also love to have some programmatic access to the console as well it would be nice to be able to track stats at the very least.

Comment: @DalmTo : 
hi there stackoverflow.com/questions/63971562/… here is my issue which seems related to your skills, I am happy to be in discussion with you if you can come on chat. if you are busy, please ans of my question, I will be thankful to you.